# Trying to run fetch function before register a service worker.

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, service-worker, race-condition

I am trying to run a fetch function which will get me some values from my server. But for some reason the registration of a service worker fires first and its leaving "app_key" undefined causing it to thrown exception. 
It seems like this is a race condition that I do not know how to solve.

I am not sure how should I assign the values to the variables to make sure they are visible by the other function. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
project_url = window.location.hostname;

var vapi_key;
var app_key;
var pushSub;
var end_point = "https://" + project_url + "/push/subscribe/create";

(() =>  {
    return fetch ("https://" + project_url + "/push/get_public_key"
    ).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((responseJSON) => {
        vapi_key = responseJSON;
        urlBase64ToUint8Array(vapi_key);
        console.log("VAPI_KEY: ", vapi_key);
        console.log("APP_KEY: ", app_key)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Fetch Error : ', err);
    });
})();


(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const permissionResult = Notification.requestPermission((result) => {
            resolve(result);
        });

        if (permissionResult) {
            permissionResult.then(resolve, reject);
        }
    })
        .then((permissionResult) => {
            if (permissionResult !== 'granted') {
                throw new Error('We weren\'t granted permission.');
            }
        });
})();

(() => {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw_bundle.js')
            .then((registration) => {
                let subscribeOptions = {
                    userVisibleOnly: true,
                    applicationServerKey: app_key,
                };

                return registration.pushManager.subscribe(subscribeOptions);
            })
            .then((pushSubscription) => {
                console.log('Received PushSubscription: ', JSON.stringify(pushSubscription));
                const subscriptionObject = {
                    endpoint: pushSubscription.endpoint,
                    keys: {
                        p256dh: pushSubscription.keys['p256dh'],
                        auth: pushSubscription.keys['auth']
                    }
                };
                sendSubscriptionToBackEnd(subscriptionObject);
                return pushSubscription;
            });
    } else {
        console.warn('Push messaging is not supported');
    }
})();

function urlBase64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
    const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
    const base64 = (base64String + padding)
        .replace(/\-/g, '+')
        .replace(/_/g, '/');
    const rawData = window.atob(base64);
    const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
        outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    app_key = outputArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure why you expect this to work. Especially why you use [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)s to create the promises. Anyway, if you want one promise to be chained to another promise, you need to make this explicit by creating the second promise in a `.then` call to the first promise. Here's an example:

```js
const createPromiseA = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
window.setTimeout(() => { console.log('promiseA'); resolve(); }, 2000);
});

const createPromiseB = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
window.setTimeout(() => { console.log('promiseB'); resolve(); }, 3000);
});

createPromiseA().then(createPromiseB);
```

In your case, you need to do something like:

```
const fetchKeys = () => fetch ("https://" + project_url + "/push/get_public_key"
    ).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((responseJSON) => {
        vapi_key = responseJSON;
        urlBase64ToUint8Array(vapi_key);
        console.log("VAPI_KEY: ", vapi_key);
        console.log("APP_KEY: ", app_key)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Fetch Error : ', err);
    });

const registerWorker = () => {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw_bundle.js')
            .then((registration) => {
                let subscribeOptions = {
                    userVisibleOnly: true,
                    applicationServerKey: app_key,
                };

                return registration.pushManager.subscribe(subscribeOptions);
            })
            .then((pushSubscription) => {
                console.log('Received PushSubscription: ', JSON.stringify(pushSubscription));
                const subscriptionObject = {
                    endpoint: pushSubscription.endpoint,
                    keys: {
                        p256dh: pushSubscription.keys['p256dh'],
                        auth: pushSubscription.keys['auth']
                    }
                };
                sendSubscriptionToBackEnd(subscriptionObject);
                return pushSubscription;
            });
    } else {
        return Promise.reject('Push messaging is not supported');
    }
};

// …

fetchKeys().then(registerWorker)
.then(() => { console.log('(!) Success!'); });
```

---

**NOTE:** An—imo—better way to utilize IIFEs would be to wrap your entire script in a function and execute it. That would bind the variables to the local scope of the function and not expose them. I.e. do something like:

```
(() => {
    project_url = window.location.hostname;

    var vapi_key;
    var app_key;
    var pushSub;
    var end_point = "https://" + project_url + "/push/subscribe/create";

    // ...

    const fetchKeys = () => { ... } ;
    const registerWorker = () => { ... } ;

    // ...

    fetchKeys().then(registerWorker)
    .then(() => { console.log('(!) Success!'); });

})();
```

Comment: Thanks <3. I am still bit new to JavaScript and I am trying to get my head around how to nest the functions and work with async and promises.

Comment: Sure, no worries. It's probably important to understand which problem promises mean to solve. A good starting point for any information on JavaScript APIs is MDN (here's the [link to their `Promise` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)).